# Figure with multiple layers - toggle with text button

Tags: graphics, latex-misc

I have been searching with google for quite some time, but I did not manage to find a satisfying answer. My problem is fairly simple:

In my paper I want to show an image which has some annotations. What I want, though, is that these annotations can be toggled on and off. An example of what I am looking for can be found in Fig. 2 in this paper:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.0032.pdf

Here the labels can simply be toggled by clicking on the text in the caption of the figure. How does this work?

thanks

Comment: EDIT: The toggle button only works in Adobe Acrobat

Comment: There are packages like [`acrotex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/acrotex) [`fancytooltips`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips), [`pdfcomment`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment) …

Comment: Digging through the example PDF, it placed multiple images in the same object and controlled the opacity with the toggle.  You might achieve the same effect placing a popup image over another image.  From what I've seen acrotex and pdfcomment just use hyperref macros, which in turn call PDF driver macros.  The lower the level, the more power you have but the more complicated using it becomes (and less well documented).